# Cannot Save or Load Models With TensorFlow & TFLEARN

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I'm going through the Titanic tutorial from [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tutorials/intro/quickstart.md).  After completeing it I wanted to save the model and then load it up later.  After saving it I get a warning saying:

```
TensorFlow's V1 checkpoint format has been deprecated.
WARNING:tensorflow:Consider switching to the more efficient V2 format:
```

When I load it I get an error saying

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for model.tflearn
 [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

This is how I saved/loaded the model.

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)


model = tflearn.DNN(net)

model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
```

and then when I load it I just do a...

```
model.load('model.tflearn')
```

If anyone who has experience with this could give me a hand I would appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `model.load('./model.tflearn')`

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]